# Tailwind css not working in Vue web component

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, web-component

I have a Vue web component. When I build it as a normal Vue component everything worked fine.  However, it lost all the Tailwind styling immediately I converted it to a Vue Web Component. Thanks for your help in advance.

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
}
```

tailwind.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

and my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue({
    template: {
      compilerOptions: {
        // treat all tags with a dash as custom elements
        isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.includes('-')
      }
    }
  })],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: './src/entry.js',
      formats: ['es','cjs'],
      name: 'web-component',
      fileName: (format)=>(format === 'es' ? 'index.js' : 'index.cjs')
    },
    sourcemap: true,
    target: 'esnext',
    minify: false
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your tailwind.config.cjs like as below

before the change tailwind.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

after changing tailwind.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the vue extension to the list of file extensions solved my issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, for now, what I have done is to add Tailwind directly to the web component and it works.

```
<style>
 @import url("../tailwind.css");
</style>
```

Comment: this does not seem a good way. but this solves my problem too.

Answer (score 0):

In src/main.js change `import "./assets/main.css";` to your tailwind css file
`

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, this was the issue for me, for some reason the 'vue add tailwind' command did not add it automatically